# отображение ходов шашки

Tags: javascript, html, css

создаю шашки и никак не могу прописать отображение ходов белых. Пробывал через создание блока и присвоение класса, но ничего не вышло
HTML:
JS:
CSS:

```js
const checkers = document.body.querySelectorAll('.checker');
const checkersB = document.body.querySelectorAll('.black');
const checkersW = document.body.querySelectorAll('.white');
let xW =0;
let yW =0;
let xB =1;
let yB =0;



    // WHITE checkers position
    for(let checkerW of checkersW){
        checkerW.style.left =`${xW*12.5}%`;
        checkerW.style.bottom =`${yW*12.5}%`;
        xW+=2;
        if(xW===8){
            xW=1;
            ++yW;
        } else if(xW===9){
            xW=0;
            ++yW;
        };
        // checker move variants display
        checkerW.addEventListener('click',() => {
             
                let VarUpR = document.createElement('div');
               
                
                VarUpR.className = 'move';
               

                

                VarUpR.style.bottom = `${checkerW.style.bottom - 12.5}%`;
                VarUpR.style.left = `${checkerW.style.left + 12.5}%`;
                checkerW.after(VarUpR);
            });
    };
// BLACK checkers position
    for(let checkerB of checkersB){
      
        checkerB.style.left =`${xB*12.5}%`;
        checkerB.style.top =`${yB*12.5}%`;
        xB+=2;
        
        if(xB===8){
            xB=1;
            ++yB;
        } else if(xB===9){
            xB=0;
            ++yB;
        };
    };
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
   
}
.chess-board{
    position: relative;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    outline: 3px solid #000;
}
.square{
    
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 12.5%;
    background-color: rgb(216, 216, 112);
    
    
}
.gray{
    
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 12.5%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 153, 0);
}
.checker{
    margin: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%;
    left: 0%;
    border:  solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.checker::after{
    content: "";
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border:  solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.white{
    bottom: 0%;
    background-color: azure;
}
.black{
    top: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
}


.move{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(128, 127, 127, 0.548);
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html{
            background-color: darkgrey;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<div class="chess-board">

    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="square gray"></div>
    <div class="square"></div>
 
    
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>
        <div class="checker white"></div>

        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
        <div class="checker black"></div>
    
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Присвоение класса - вполне работоспособная идея. Я только не понимаю, если все дивы никак не идентифицируются, как же шашка должна менять позицию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал первую версию: можно ходить но бить пока нельзя

логика хода - `в функции addMoveToClickListener`

https://jsfiddle.net/7tpdm98v/4/

Посмотрите внимательно на получившийся html код,
есть таблица с ячейками, для примера таблица 2x2:

```
<table>
   <tr rowIndex="0"> <td columnIndex="0"></td> <td columnIndex="1"> </tr>
   <tr rowIndex="1"> <td columnIndex="0"></td> <td columnIndex="1"> </tr>
<table>
```

а сама шашка - это div внутри ячейки (внутри td), при ходе - меняется положениеи у этого div'а

При клике на шашку - вызывается `handler` который в навешан в функции `addClickListenerToChecker`: значения `rowIndex и columnIndex` шашки присваиваются в переменные:

```
activeCheckerRowIndex;
activeCheckerColumnIndex;
```

потом при клике на поле в которое можно походить вызывается  `handler` который навешан в функции `addMoveToClickListenerToCell`
в котором высчитываются `rowIndex и columnIndex` этой ячейки и уже идет проверка - можно ли походить сюда активной шашкой или нет.

если да - вызывается функция `moveChecker`, в которой удаляется шашка из старой ячейки `(td)` и добавляется в новую.

Comment: Вау! Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!